# Track Multiple Domains with analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics

We have a site that has the same content but available under two domains. Is this is the right code to put on each page to split the domains in google analytics so we can see view the activity under each domain?

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-1234-1' {'cookieDomain': 'domain1.com.au'});
  ga('create', 'UA-1234-2' {'cookieDomain': 'domain2.co.nz'});
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced (part **Working with Multiple Tracking Objects**) you should create a named tracker for the second property, like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'domain1.com'});
ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', {'name': 'newTracker', 'cookieDomain': 'domain2.com'});  // New tracker.
```

and then send the page view for each tracker:

```
ga('send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for default tracker UA-XXXX-Y
ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for new tracker.
```

There's also other way how to track the same website with 2 domains by using just one property (UA-1234-1) and creating 2 views with each will include traffic only from given domain names (*use [predefined filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162) "Exclude/Include only traffic from the domains"*)

***UPDATE***

Thinking again about my answer, I must admit that even the original solution in answer

```
ga('create', 'UA-1234-1' {'cookieDomain': 'domain1.com.au'});
ga('create', 'UA-1234-2' {'cookieDomain': 'domain2.co.nz'});
```

will work, because if you try to create tracker 'UA-1234-1' on domain `domain2.co.nz` cookie will not be set (and vice versa creating 'UA-1234-2' on domain `domain1.com.au`). My solution is technically OK, but then you must take care about sending all pageviews, event trackings and other informations twice - for default tracker and also for named tracker.

Sorry if this is little confusing.